# Word VBA use Regex for formatting change

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a word document that has SQL code in it. I have great code that finds specific terms I didn't realize that I had so many different terms in my document. I stopped at over 140 terms. I tried to add regex but I did it wrong. Would it be possible to have it find the start word SELECT and the end word FROM and change the background color to wdBrightGreen for everything between those terms?
I did not put all the fields in I stopped at three. Is there a way to put the ArrFind to search the whole document instead of specific terms?

```
Dim ArrFnd As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim regexObject As RegExp

Dim strField1(1 To 200) As String
Dim strField2(1 To 20) As String
strField1(1) = "SELECT DISTINCT    policy_id"
strField1(2) = "SELECT DISTINCT  policy_id"
strField1(3) = "SELECT DISTINCT   P.policy_id"

For x = 1 To 150
    ArrFnd = Array(strField1(x))
    With ActiveDocument
        For i = 0 To UBound(ArrFnd)
            With .Range
                With .Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Format = False
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .MatchCase = True
                .MatchWholeWord = True
                        .Text = ArrFnd(i)
                    With regexObject
                         .Pattern = "[SELECT-FROM]"
                    End With
                .Replacement.Text = ""
            End With
                Do While .Find.Execute
                    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                    Loop
            End With
        Next i
    End With
Next x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One wonders why you persist with the approach taken in your code, in light of: [MS Word VBA Can't select specific words to change background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425926/ms-word-vba-cant-select-specific-words-to-change-background-color/72427667#72427667)

Regardless, for what you are now describing, all you need is:

```
Sub HiliteWords()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "SELECT[!^13^l]@FROM"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    .Start = .Words.First.End
    .End = .Words.Last.Start - 1
    .Font.Shading.BackgroundPatternColorIndex = wdBrightGreen
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If you also don't want DISTINCT shaded, insert:

```
If .Words.First.Text = "DISTINCT " Then .Start = .Words.First.End
```

before:

```
    .End = .Words.Last.Start - 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is not working. It seems that the end function is not working because the highlighting starts after the first select but continues and highlights the rest of the code on the sheet till I get to the 26th FROM. I did notice that all the FROM's that were skipped are at the beginning of the sentence, the one that the formatting stopped at was 20 characters indented from the 1st spot on that line.

Comment: An example is:  SELECT DISTINCT 
       p.policy_id
FROM dbo.policy_payer_option polpo (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.policy p (NOLOCK)
        ON p.series_id = polpo.series_id
           AND p.cert_no = polpo.cert_no   In this example I would expect that only p.policy_id woyld be highlighted

Comment: An example is:  
SELECT DISTINCT 
       p.policy_id
FROM dbo.policy_payer_option polpo (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN dbo.policy p (NOLOCK)
        ON p.series_id = polpo.series_id
           AND p.cert_no = polpo.cert_no 
  
In this example I would expect that only p.policy_id 
would be highlighted, but everything is highlighted.

Comment: See revised code.

Comment: I added the If .Words.First.Text = "DISTINCT " Then .Start = .Words.First.End and it did avoid the Select Distinct. Unfortunately there are 79 instances of Select  and it only picks three cases : SELECT 1 FROM , SELECT * FROM

Comment: The issue here is your lack of clarity regarding what you want. I am not going to play a guessing game.

Comment: I closed the program and opened it up again and now it works, thanks so much.